# Emacs strange appearance

Tags: arch-linux, kde, emacs, desktop, menu

After update the newest version of KDE (Plasma ver. 5.6.3, Frameworks 5.21.0) and kernel 4.5.2-1 ARCH, the menu bar of Emacs becomes ugly

[image: Emacs menu bar]

The same error appears in Firefox: the options in right-click menus is very tight. However, it is normal in all other applications. Except this error, Emacs and Firefox still work flawlessly. Any ideas?

Comment: Your theme, like a lot of other people's, was broken by the GTK update. Change it to one that has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to @jasonwryan's comment, I did some search and found the solution in [this link](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=361066) (Icecube63 comment). I post it literally here just in case the link is unavailable:

'There is a typo in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`. It should be lowercase, not "Breeze":

```
[Settings]
gtk-theme-name=breeze
gtk-icon-theme-name=breeze
```

After changing all gtk3 applications look fine.'